# iOS 7 multipeer connectivity streaming audio

Tags: iphone, ios7, bluetooth, wifi, multipeer-connectivity

Does anyone know if it's possible to live stream my iOS device microphone's audio signal to other iOS devices in "real time"? I want to use the multipeer connectivity framework via wifi or Bluetooth.

Thank you

this is how it send and recieve message

SendCallback:

```
- (IBAction)SendMessage:(id)sender {
  NSString *message = self.tfMessage.text;
  self.tfMessage.text = @"";
  NSData *data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSError *error;
  [self.Session sendData:data toPeers:[self.Session connectedPeers] withMode:MCSessionSendDataUnreliable error:&error];
  [self receiveMessage: message fromPeer: self.PeerID];
}
```

ReceiveCallback:

```
- (void) receiveMessage: (NSString *) message fromPeer: (MCPeerID *) peer{
  NSString *formatedMessage;
  if (peer == self.PeerID) {
    formatedMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@: %@ \n", peer.displayName, message];
  }else{
    formatedMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@: %@ \n", peer.displayName, message];
  }
  self.tvMessages.text = [self.tvMessages.text stringByAppendingString:formatedMessage];
}
```

Init:

```
self.PeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[UIDevice currentDevice].name];
self.Session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.PeerID];
self.Session.delegate = self;
self.browserViewController = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat" session:self.Session];
self.browserViewController.delegate = self;
self.advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat" discoveryInfo:nil session:self.Session];
[self.advertiser start];
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What was exactly your problem (the connectivity? getting the microphone Signal?)? Please show us the affected code

Comment: No i'm not, i can create peers and connect them each other within a session so i can send text message from one to another and back but what should i use to send for example audio? how should i do that?

Comment: Please show us the code you have get so far (for sending text messages from one peer to another). Then we can try to help you adapting it to send audio data instead (hint: audio data is still just like 'text' - with numbers instead of alphanumeric characters).

Comment: see code above thank you

Comment: It should be possible to do this. GameKit supports voicechat over bluetooth and internet. With bluetooth you are limited to 8 persons though. My lucky guess is that Apple also uses Multipeer internally here.

Comment: as far as i know gkvoicechat is depricated in ios 7

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity/) code. It seems to use CoreAudio, so you should be able to open the Mic AudioUnit and change the code above slightly.

Comment: It didnt worked for me. Its just showing the song info and images but no songs getting played

Answer (score 0):

Use [GKVoiceChat](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKVoiceChat_Ref/Reference/Reference.html), it simply needs some hooks to wire data into. GameKit itself is deprecated in iOS 7, but this tiny little service seems not. Actually it has nothing to do with the rest of GameKit services.

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943520/peer-to-peer-voice-chat-between-via-bluetooth-or-in-a-local-wifi-network-in-ios