# Peer to Peer Voice chat between via bluetooth or in a local WiFi network in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gamekit, livechat

I want to implement the voice chat between two iOS devices without using WiFi or cellular network within the range of Bluetooth.

I have done the text chat within Bluetooth range using multipeer connectivity framework, But I also want to do voice chat like text chat within the Bluetooth range.

I found that we can implement the voice chat using GameKit but I have not found any reference of tutorial yet, How to Implement voice chat.

**UPDATE:**
I found that the GameKit VoiceChatService has been deprecated after iOS 7.0.
is There another way to call another iOS device on the same network.

I found that this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ip2pvoicechat-bluetooth-wifi/id908638157?mt=8 work calls the user on the same wifi network.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43756 ... This is a pretty old article , but seems to do what you are looking for. You will have to translate it to latest syntax

Comment: @humblePilgrim can I use multipeer connectivity for voice chat

Comment: @humblePilgrim because it show the deprecated for game kit

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a Bluetooth connection, you should just **start sending chunks of audio data**.

I made a library years ago that can read / play audio stream. See [**eppz!capture**](https://github.com/eppz/iOS.Library.eppz_capture) for more. [`EPPZCapture`](https://github.com/eppz/iOS.Library.eppz_capture/blob/master/eppz!capture/EPPZCapture.h) and [`EPPZCaptureBufferParser`](https://github.com/eppz/iOS.Library.eppz_capture/blob/master/eppz!capture/EPPZCaptureBufferParser.h) in particular. They provide / consume [`CMSampleBufferRef`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmsamplebufferref) together.

I don't support this code, but you can use it as some source of inspiration for your own streaming code.

---

However, there are countless libraries for that, like https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit, https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer, https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer.

---

Furthermore, I think you can still use [`GKVoiceChat`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkvoicechat), classes are there. Docs above don't even show deprecation (while the compiler may show).

Comment: Thanks for your response. If GKVoiceChat we can use so please give me some reference or sample project regarding this

Comment: Well, I can recommend the internets.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkvoicechat, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741185/gkvoicechat-example, https://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1, whatnot.

Comment: There is no clear description, just start making a prototype, and you will be fine. Unfortunately the applications I made using this are not under my control.

Comment: I could only recreate some code, but that would consume way too many time.

Comment: Sir, I am using the TDAudioStream Class for voice chat, but this only send the mp3 file and my recorder save the file in m4a format, so I am converting the m4a to mp3 but it taking time so how to achieve this?

Comment: Don't think you should save anything, juust play back an audio buffer. I advise you to hire someone.